# Can someone please comment on the efficiency of Mathematica, Maple and Matlab in conditional plotting?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy, discontinuity

I use Mathematica to plot

```
f[x_] := -(1/
    8) (18 - 280 x^2 - 4 x^4 + 8 x^6 + 
     2 x^8 + (81 + 108 x^2 + 54 x^4 + 12 x^6 + x^8) Cos[
       4 π x] + (-64 + 128 x^2 - 64 x^4) Cos[
       2 (-2 + Sqrt[5]) π x] + (1 - 4 x^2 + 6 x^4 - 4 x^6 + 
        x^8) Cos[
       4 (-2 + Sqrt[5]) π x] + (-18 + 24 x^2 + 4 x^4 - 8 x^6 - 
        2 x^8) Cos[
       2 π x - 2 (-2 + Sqrt[5])π x] + (-18 + 24 x^2 + 
        4 x^4 - 8 x^6 - 2 x^8) Cos[
       2 π x + 2 (-2 + Sqrt[5]) π x]) Sin[π x]^2;
Plot[{0, If[f[x] >= 0, 10^1.5]}, {x, 0, 200}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[White, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[-1], 
    Thickness[0]], 
   Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[10^10], Thickness[.05]]},
  PlotPoints -> 500, MaxRecursion -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/40, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

Even when I use `PlotPoints-> 5*10^6` and `MaxRecursion-> 15` it does not give me the whole result, some parts of the solutions are missing (I notice this when I plot it for a short domain like $90<x<100$). Then, can I be hoping to get the whole result by other software like Matlab or Maple? If someone has had experience in working with all these programs, please tell me which program is more efficient in detailed plotting? I am not familiar with those programs, and I want to know if they are more accurate in this sense, try them out.

Another question, if I increase the number of `PlotPoints` to $10^{10}$, will it be safe for my laptop (core i7)? Since it takes much time and fan starts working loudly.

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't spotted underlying issue correctly. Do notice the display of graphics is limited by the resolution of your monitor, and even with a 4K screen, you have only `4096*2160.=8.84736*10^6` pixels for display. Without a concrete example it's hard to give further advice, but anyway, have you adjusted `WorkingPrecision`? Have you tried `ReIm`?

Comment: Commenting on MATLAB/Maple is off-topic here. Can you edit that part out of your question to avoid it getting closed? After that, please give a *minimal* example that illustrates the issue, and remove absurd and dangerous parameters such as `PlotPoints -> 5000000`, as they may lock up the computer of someone who tries this naively.

Comment: Can you explain in words what you are trying to do? Do you want to plot a function whose value is 1 when $f(x)>0$ and 0 otherwise?

Comment: You can use `UnitStep@f@Range[0, 200, 0.001]` for fast computation.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. I removed $5000000$ from the code. Yes, I need a plot of the function $f$ showing $1$ when it is greater and equal to zero. Then can I use the result of $UnitStep$ to plot them?

Comment: @Szabolcs Are these huge numbers for PlotPoint very dangerous for the computer? I tried them a lot with my laptop:( I asked here some time but nobody said that it is harmful for the system.

Comment: @charmin No, they will not damage your computer. They _might_ lock up your system temporarily, and if you are forced to reboot (or kill Mathematica), you might lose a bit of work. But this will not do any damage to the computer, no need to worry about that. If the fan is working, it just means that you are making full use of the machine :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

There's no doubt that `Plot` can handle a smooth function better, so why not first plot the smooth `f[x]` and then transform it to the step-like target?:

```
p = Plot[f[x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 2500, 
    MaxRecursion -> 15]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {61.1839, Null} *)

{xlst, ylst} = Cases[p, Line[{a__}] :> a, Infinity] // Transpose;

pts = With[{ystep = ylst // UnitStep}, 
        {xlst, ystep // N}\[Transpose][[
          Sort@Flatten@{1, SequencePosition[ystep, {0, 1}], 
                           SequencePosition[ystep, {1, 0}], Length@xlst}]]];

pstep = Graphics[{ColorData[1][1], Line[pts]}, PlotRange -> All];

Manipulate[Show[pstep, PlotRange -> {{a, a + 1}, {0, 1.2}}, Axes -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], {a, 0, 199}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is useful, but as I wrote in the text, I need a plot which seems impossible.

Comment: @charmin The `pstep` is the plot you need, but as mentioned in the comment under your question, I don't think there exists a screen that can properly display such a picture.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of extensive computations being dangerous to a computer. I've left Mathematica running overnight on occasion with all cores firing and never had an issue. Perhaps if all you were doing was continuously shifting bits around on your solid state drive for weeks on end or something crazy you might reduce its life a bit.

As for Mathematica vs. Maple vs. MATLAB, I don't think this is an issue with the program and I think you would have the exact same issue not matter what program. I think it would be good for you to play around with your function and understand it a bit better, because its properties make it difficult to plot. The peak height grows extremely rapidly while the width of each peak gets smaller and smaller.

Let's take a look at a peak around x = 199.018.

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 199.017}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 199.019}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(* x -> 199.01818 *)
(* x -> 199.01863 *)
```

So the difference is about 0.00045. Over the whole width of 0 to 200, at 4k resolution that would be 0.00045/200*4096 = 0.0092 pixels. So it would need to be 100 times wider in order to be a single pixel wider. I'm not 100% sure how Mathematica decides whether to print a line or not, but I would bet that it needs to be at least 0.5 pixels wide. At a glance, it doesn't look like there are many peaks beyond 20 that would be wide enough to print.

If you want to make certain it displays at least a 1 pixel width every time it's above zero, you could try:

```
Plot[
  f[x],
  {x, 0, 200},
  AspectRatio -> 1/10,
  Filling -> Axis,
  FillingStyle -> {None, Directive[ColorData[97][1], Opacity[0.5]]},
  PlotPoints -> 100000,
  PlotRange -> {0, 10}
]
```

[image: Plot of f[x].]

Frankly, that doesn't seem very useful. If you expand it horizontally to take up more pixels, you might be able to see some of the gaps, but does it tell you anything worthwhile?

We can also try to calculate some points manually.

```
data = Table[{N[x], N[f[x]]}, {x, 0, 200, 1/1000}];
cases = Cases[data, {_, _?NonNegative}];
Graphics[{
    AbsoluteThickness[1],
    Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 10}}] & /@ cases[[All, 1]]
  },
  Axes -> {True, False},
  AxesLabel -> {"x"}
]
```

[image: Stick plot of f[x].]

Here, I've simply calculated the range from 0 to 200 in steps of 1/1000, and if it's greater than or equal to 0, I add a line 1 pixel wide to my image. However, I know for a fact that I'm missing at least that first peak that I mentioned (199.01818 to 199.01863) as it easily fits in between by data points. Probably, if I make the width even smaller, I would just end up with a solid black bar.

With a step size of 1/10000 and using `ParallelTable`:

[image]

With a step size of 1/10000, using `ParallelTable`, `ImageSize -> 2500`, and bumping up the label size:

[image]

It's possible that I'm still missing some peaks that are too narrow, but I wonder how useful this graph is considering many of the peaks are made artificially wider by factors of 100 or more. I think you'll have to think very carefully about how you want to represent this function. If you only care about seeing whether there exists a peak, then this could be useful to you. If you need to understand their relative widths, then that's probably what you're getting with your current code—it's just that many are too narrow to show in a finite number of pixels.